# Understanding variable update in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused, by what might be a simple topic. I first encountered this today and was a little startled. Suppose you have the following code

```
let x = {a: 100}
let y = {b: x} //Note the x value
```

Now the interesting part is when you update `x`

```
x.a = 200

console.log(x)
console.log(y)

> { a: 200 }
> { b: { a: 200 } }
```

It gets updated in both objects. I was under the impression that `y` would create a brand new object despite using a reference to `x`. Now my mind is blown by this fact. What is going on here? What is the topic being illuminated here?

Answer (score 0):

In your case that just makes a shallow copy of the same object. In order to create a new Object(deep copy) use `Object.assign`

```js
let x = {
  a: 100
}
let y = {
  b: Object.assign({}, x)
}

x.a = 200;

console.log(x)
console.log(y)
```